# Custom transition for push animation with NavigationController on iOS 9

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, custom-transition

I have a custom push transition between view controllers embedded in a `UINavigationController` which is working fine when built with iOS 7/8 but presents a wrong layout when built against iOS 9 SDK.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
  UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
  UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

  [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

  ...
```

It then goes on and performs an animation. The issue is that the content of the `toViewController`, even though it is using the right top layout guide auto layout constraint, presents the content behind the navigation bar.

Nevertheless, it works fine on iOS 8 and if we force a redraw (e.g., sending the app to the background and bring it back, present a modal on top and dismiss it, etc) will cause the whole auto layout system to redraw itself and `toViewController`'s view jumps to the right place (as being the top layout guide, x pixels from the navigation bar rather than x pixels from the top of the device's screen).

Adding

```
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Works if put in `viewDidAppear:animated`, but does not work on `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:animated`. This is not a solution as users would see the view jumping when the redraw is happening at `viewDidAppear:animated`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've managed to fix my issue by adding the following line before `addSubview:`:

```
  toViewController.view.frame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toViewController];
```

From Apple's Documentation for [finalFrameForViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning/finalFrameForViewController:)

> Returns the ending frame rectangle for the specified view controller’s
>   view.
>
> The rectangle returned by this method represents the size
>   of the corresponding view at the end of the transition. For the view
>   being covered during the presentation, the value returned by this
>   method might be CGRectZero but it might also be a valid frame
>   rectangle.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of hours. Thanks a lot!