# iOS- How to disable animations in unwind segues programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, unwind-segue

I've created some unwind segues in XCode and by default they come with an animation which I don't want. After some searching around in Stack Overflow I did find that there is supposed to be a check box you can untick to disable animation, but that comes in Xcode 7 which I cannot upgrade to. How would I disable the unwind segue animation programmatically? I'm currently running XCode 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's name controller you are unwinding to `FirstController` and the one you are dismissing `SecondController`. Also there are two cases here: one when `SecondController` presented modally and one with `UINavigationController` involved.

Unwind segue resets/ignores `modalPresentationStyle`, have to tweak it. In `IBAction` method called on `FirstController` upon unwinding add the following (I will assume you called this method `prepareForUnwind`):

```
- (IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    //TODO: add right condition if you have to
    UIViewController* secondController = (UIViewController*)segue.sourceViewController;
    secondController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    secondController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
}
```

This part will work when `SecondController` is dismissed from being modal. Now, for case when both controllers reside on `UINavigationController`, `FirstController` should become its delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}
```

This will make UIKit to ask `FirstController` for animator object for ensuing transitions. Now we should modify `FirstController` to return it.

In `FirstController.h`:

```
@interface FirstController : UIViewController<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Add corresponding code to `FirstController.m`, so it would return some animator object for both cases (**mind comments**):

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
    return [Animator new];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
    //This will disable ALL animations on particular UINavigationController
    //return nil to use default animation when appropriate
    return [Animator new];
}
```

Now implement `Animator` itself. It should confirm `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol.

In `Animator.h`:

```
@interface Animator : NSObject<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end
```

In `Animator.m`:

```
@implementation Animator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(nullable id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *controllerToDismiss = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIView *viewToDismiss = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];
    CGRect frameToDismissTo = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:controllerToDismiss];
    viewToDismiss.frame = frameToDismissTo;

    UIViewController *controllerToPresent = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *viewToPresent = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey];
    CGRect frameToPresentTo = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:controllerToPresent];
    viewToPresent.frame = frameToPresentTo;

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:viewToPresent];

    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}

@end
```

---

Answer based on this [post](https://coderwall.com/p/njtb0q/custom-transitions-on-ios-7-a-little-bit-about-ux) and this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569488/navigation-controller-custom-transition-animation) (both not mine)