# Inside UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning delegate, the transitionContext.fromViewController is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition, custom-transition

I have a *UINavigationController* setup and am expecting to use a custom animation for pop / push of views with it.  I have used custom transitions before without issue, but in this case I am actually finding nil values in my 'from' and 'to' *UIViewControllers*.

My setup is very similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569488/navigation-controller-custom-transition-animation)

Custom DataEntryViewController

```
class DataEntryViewController : UIViewController, DataEntryViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {        
        let animator = DataEntryTransitionAnimator()
        animator.duration = 2
        return animator
    }
}
```

Custom BaseTransitionAnimator

```
class BaseTransitionAnimator : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var duration : NSTimeInterval = 0.5             // default transition time of 1/2 second
    var appearing : Bool = true                     // is the animation appearing (or disappearing)

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        assert(true, "animateTransition MUST be implemented by child class")
    }
}
```

Subclassed TransitionAnimator

```
class DataEntryTransitionAnimator : BaseTransitionAnimator {

    override func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey) as! DataEntryViewController
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey) as! DataEntryViewController
        let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        // do fancy animations
    }
}
```

Using the above, both **fromVC** and **toVC** are nil

How is it possible that the *transitionContext* doesn't have valid pointers to the 'to' and 'from' *UIViewControllers*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `UITransitionContextFromViewKey` but you need to use `UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey`

same for "to"

Comment: :facepalm:  Ha, thanks.  I was debugging on the command line AND looking in the debug window as well, swore that it showed nil for the VCs but probably due to optionals it just looked funny.  Still getting used to Swift.

Comment: No worries! Simple typo, it's easy to miss. 