# Push Transparent UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I know this question has been asked a lot, but no solution works with me.
Simply I want to push a transparent UIViewController (not Modal), just a simple push to my UINavigationController.

The problem is that I want to get rid of the flicker that occurs, any ideas?

Comment: can you share code and also screen shot?

Comment: When you push a new `UIViewController` to the `UINavigationController` the `UIViewController` below it disappears when the transition ends. Can you be more specific about the flicker?

Comment: why don't you add the view of the `UIViewController` as `subview` to the parent `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy. You need to provide your own transition. 
In transition code you will preserve view fromViewControler and it is done. If you don't do that you will see black background.

Tutorial is here:
[Navigation controller custom transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569488/navigation-controller-custom-transition-animation)