# I have a storyboard, and I push this. I want to get the name of the control on the storyboard before I launch the controller. how?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a storyBoard, and I push this. I want to get the name of the controller on the storyBoard before I launch the controller. how?

```
if let foodSearchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodSearchViewController") as? FoodSearchViewController {
    let searchView = foodSearchVC.searchContainView
    transition = Transition(fromView: seatchContainView, toView: searchView ?? UIView())
    navigationController?.delegate = transition
    foodSearchVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(foodSearchVC, animated: true)
}
```

This `searchView` is `nil`, But I want to get `searchView`

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to access any of the subviews within `foodSearchVC` because they haven't been created yet; you can only access these after `foodSearchVC viewDidLoad`.

Off the top of my head I believe you may be able to do what you need to do within the `prepareForSegue` method, however if you can't you can leverage `NSNotificationCenter`

However, it appears that you're trying to do custom transitions and what the code you've posted isn't quite how the transitions API works.

[This fantastic SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569703/9897665) shows how to do this properly