# iOS 13 custom transition using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning while presenting modal weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a custom transition between viewcontrollers that fades the current VC out and the new one in which works great, but on iOS 13 now when the viewcontroller is presented modally with its new transition where you can still see the previous VC in the background, my transition is  overriding it, I would like it to keep the gap at the top and the rounded corners instead of becoming fullscreen.

Example of it working the old way (ive slowed the animations down):

[image]

how it looks on iOS 13:

[image]

this is the code im using to do the transition:

```
class FadeAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

  func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 3
  }

  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
      let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
      else {
        return
    }

    let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    transitionContext.containerView.backgroundColor = .white
    transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
    transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(fromVC.view)

    toVC.view.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
      toVC.view.alpha = 1
      fromVC.view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { _ in
      transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    })
  }
}
```

the `snapshot` and the `toVC` are the ones becomes the full size of the screen instead of remaining the same size and shape of the `fromVC`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your call:

```
transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(fromVC.view)
```

You shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: I did try take that out initially, but it seems the make the `fromVC` do a weird default transition of its own, it sort of fades out and shrinks, probably something to do with it being presented modally

Comment: also leaves a weird gap at the bottom (i took out making the containerView background white, think that is half the problem here) https://imgur.com/a/rMwXjo6

Comment: That's an interesting problem. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: @Fonix I think what you're going to need to do is use view controller containment.

Comment: so i present like a view controller modally that will contain like a navigation controller that will do all my transitions?

Comment: @Fonix Yes, but you'll still need to imple,ent your fade transition

Comment: This [Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) should help you

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was overriding the wrong type of transition, I should have been overriding the navigation controllers transition and not the view controllers one. So i was effectively creating my own modal presentation transitions instead of the normal show/push animation which is why it was covering the iOS 13 modal transition. I implemented what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180326/1219956) and it worked well